# Selecting records younger then 2 minutes with DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, datediff

I'm currently facing the following problem:

- I want to select all the records from my database table LocationUpdates for a specific RFIDTagID AND a ScannedTime smaller then 2 min compared to the current time.
- I am giving sql two parameters: 1. RFIDTagID (Needed to select only results in the database with this tagID, 2. ScannedTime (CurrentTimeStamp).
- Now I want to ask the databse: Give me all records for RFIDTagID 123456789 where the ScannedTime max 2 min earlier is than the second parameter ScannedTime.
- When SQL returns results: Than don't add the row.
- Whenm SQL doesn't return results: Than you have to add the row.

I am making a stored procedure to perform this task. It looks like the following:

- CREATE PROCEDURE
- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.LocationUpdates updates WHERE updates.RFIDTagID = @RFIDTagID AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @ScannedTime, updates.ScannedTime) < 2
- IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN PERFORM SOME TASKS AND ADD THE ROW
- ELSE DO NOTHING

I have the following data in my database:

```
160 300833B2DDD9014035050005    18-7-2013 11:18:44
161 300833B2DDD9014035050005    18-7-2013 11:19:50
162 300833B2DDD9014035050005    18-7-2013 11:24:03
163 300833B2DDD9014035050005    18-7-2013 13:38:50
164 300833B2DDD9014035050005    18-7-2013 13:39:29
165 300833B2DDD9014035050005    1-1-1900 0:00:00
```

AND When I execute the following query (With the currentdate):

```
DECLARE @return_value Int
DECLARE @currDate DATETIME
SET @currDate = GETDATE()

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[INSERT_LOCALROW]
        @RFIDTagID = N'300833B2DDD9014035050005',           
        @ScannedTime = @currDate

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This query returns the following result: 6 rows
But I am expecting to get 0 rows in return as none of the result is two minutes different then the current time.

Someone has any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I have found already the answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.LocationUpdates updates WHERE updates.RFIDTagID = @RFIDTagID AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @ScannedTime, updates.ScannedTime) > -2
```

The function DateDiff gives a negative int when you compare a newer date with an older date, so it will return -2 when the time in the database is two minutes earlier then the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @ScannedTime, updates.ScannedTime) < 2
```

Cause if the second argument is bigger than the third argument (the dates), you will have a negative result. And... a negative result is smaller than 2.

by

```
updates.ScannedTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -2, @ScannedTime)
```

or invert parameters

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  updates.ScannedTime, @ScannedTime) < 2
```

Comment: THanks! I inverted the parameter so the function is returning a postive int. Have a nice day!